# Spring Boot + Thymeleaf: Summernote editor makes my text display a lot lower in the card than needed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, summernote

I have added summernote to my application and I use it when I add the content of a Post object for a blog. It seems summernote adds a lot of attributes to the tags that surround the string which makes the post display a lot lower in the Card.

This is how `post.content` looks like when I submit it with summernote

```
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span style="font-size: 18px;">What happens here?</span></p>
<ul>
<li><span style="font-size: 18px;">This is cool</span></li>
<li><span style="font-size: 18px;">So Cool</span></li>
</ul>
<p><span style="font-size: 18px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><font color="#000000">No idea</font></span></p>
```

This is how a post.content looks like which is not summited with the summernote text editor

```
wqodij qwdn fnfj wofnef v veofn w ow w nwwn o wowew oo wn&nbsp; n fner ino wo we or 2om womweo4o io&nbsp; o o4 o mo mw we mo o wofwe o om o owwe owo o mwef wo wo o o wof wo o om o3m o23mr o23 dof wo o o2 omom weofm oi 3o2m o m2oowefm owem o23
```

and this is how the whole thing looks like
[image]
[image]

As you can see the String that was posted with summernote is a lot lower on the page than the other one. How can I make it show at the same level? What solutions are there? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I use in thymeleaf

```
<h2 class="mb-3" th: text="${post.title}"></h2>

<div th: utext="${post.content}"></div>
```

Comment: (1) Avoid using inline `style`; it's been considered generally bad form for decades. (2) Your Thymeleaf is outputting well-formed HTML; the way your page is displayed is entirely up to the HTML and CSS rules, so it's all about _what content you put in the Thymeleaf template_.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- hi and thanks for answer. I am not puting style in there, summernote is doing that by itself, i am just inputing a text and click submit and if i apply any text options from summernote(like text color, size, font etc) it will add all those options for me. I just found something about a tag parser called Jsoup, any idea if it would be good in this case ?

Comment: The text is lower due to `&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;` that is present in the output of summernote. You will need to find out why summernote outputs that, or somehow "clean up" what you get from summernote in your Java application.